# Xcode : Build Failed

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, apple-developer-account

The Xcode failed when trying to build the app. I have two error messages :

-Cannot create a iOS App Development provisioning profile for "MY_PROJECT_FILE".
Personal development teams, including "MY_NAME", do not support the Push Notifications capability.

-Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'MY_PROJECT_FILE'.

I have a developper account but didn't pay for it. Do I have to pay the enrollment  to avoid those messages ?